# $_GET is not working

Tags: php, get

Creating a rating system and the info is not being transmitted through my $_GET variable. The code is below

```
    if (isset($_GET['item'], $_GET['rating'])){
echo 'Works!';
}
```

The variable is being entered in this code below

```
  <?php echo number_format( 
        $article['rating'],1); ?>
        <div class = "rate">
            Rate:
            <?php
            for ($x =1; $x<= $maximum_rating; $x++){
            ?>
                <a href="prestige.php?item=<?php echo $article['id']; ?>&rating=<?php echo $x;?>">
                <?php echo $x; ?></a>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

I am fairly new to programming so any ideas or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That `&` should be `&amp;` but I 'm not sure if that would prevent things from working in this case...

Comment: When you click on the URL, what does appear in the browser address bar?

Comment: Is your php code actually in the file `prestige.php`?

Comment: 1. Have you looked at the HTML code in the browser to confirm that the link is actually correct? ie the ID and rating values are populated?
2. Does anything else in the prestige.php page work? If you move the "works" message above the `if()` block, does it now appear?

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump( $_GET );` or `var_dump( $_REQUEST );` just before your `isset()` line, and access the URL?

Comment: Shows array(0) { } when I use the code var_dump($_GET) @SetSailMedia

Comment: Yes the 'works' message still appears. And yes the id and ratings values are populated @Spudley

Comment: @Octavius, so we can determine the parameters aren't making it to the URL request, and thus not making it into PHP's `$_GET` variable. If you place this code the same place you put `var_dump`, what do you see? `echo( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );`

Comment: &amp shows what I'm pressing in the browser and the code I am using @Jon

Comment: I see my directory that's also in my browser. /Series/New/prestige.php @SetSailMedia

Comment: Can you put `<?php var_dump($_GET); die(); ?>` as first line of `prestige.php`? And call it with populated parameters? This would reduce the possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things you should do.

**1.**
Instead of

```
prestige.php?item=<?php echo $article['id']; ?>&rating=<?php echo $x;?>
```

Use

```
prestige.php?<?= http_build_query(array('item' => $article['id'], 'rating' => $x), '&amp;') ?>
```

This will escape the parameters. Vars `$article['id']` and `$x` could contain characters that break the HTML or URL.

**2.** 
Look at the Net tab in your Firebug/Chrome dev toolbar. Are there any redirects? What headers are sent?

Also look at the address bar to see if prestige.php really is loaded with the GET parameters.

**3.**
Use a debug tool like [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) to step through your code. You might have some code that resets the `$_GET` vars. Personally I use the IDE PHPed, but it's kinda expensive.

Comment: +1 for introducing PHP5's `http_build_query`. Probably should -1 for still using short open tags, but I won't :}

Comment: @SetSailMedia I really think you should *always* use short open tags in templates, as long as you don't depend on shared hosting..

Comment: Once a fan, always a fan. I'll never convert you all! :}

Comment: I so frustrated, my echo 'works' is still not working and just prestige.php is showing in the address bar. Was unsure of where to look for redirects, but I didn't see anything that said redirects. @Znarkus

Comment: @Octavius http://getfirebug.com/network you should see multiple page requests. Also, hover the link and look in the status bar to see if the correct URL is shown.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted works. So the snag must be in the code you *did not* post:

1. maybe the `prestige.php` page has a PHP error that prevents it from displaying anything; start with an empty file containing just `<?php echo 'OK so far'; ?>`.
2. maybe the page contains code (security checks, frameworks...) that kills $_GET. (reduce the page to a minimum working case, without include/requires)
3. maybe the page *does* work, but the output gets snarked by an untimely `ob_end_clean()` that was meant to "clean the page" before the real output started; (reduce the page to a minimum working case)
4. maybe the page works, the string 'Works' is there, but you can't see it due to HTML markup, CSS, or other rendering problems (check the page source)
5. the URL might be broken because the item code contains invalid URL characters (check what appears in the browser address bar)
6. there might be an URL rewrite scheme that interferes (check .htaccess and the server logs)
7. I just remembered something like this happening with international characters in the URL. Try with an ASCII-clean item code to see what happens.
8. Just to be sure: verify there is no `auto_prepend`'ed file which might interfere.

Then, it might also be *more than one* of the above acting together. Often when debugging one unintentionally breaks some code, and even after fixing the first bug, the code doesn't start working again - this doesn't mean the fix was invalid.

I'm sorry -- I'm at the end of my options. I really look forward to knowing what the reason was. (*Usually the more explanations I amass, the more the real answer tends to be "none of the above". When it happens to me, sometimes I wonder whether to start to believe in gremlins* :-( ).

Comment: @Znarkus, I kind of like yours better; I did not think of redirects. Based on my past experience, this means *that*'s the answer. That, or gremlins :-)